# Does existence of a limit of a composition of functions implies existence of the limit of the individual functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) = u(v(x))$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$.

What are the (minimal) conditions on $u$ and $v$ for the above to imply the existence of the following two limits?

$\tag{1} \lim_{x \to a} v(x) = b$
$\tag{2} \lim_{y \to b} u(y) = L$

For example, the implication does not hold for both limits when $v(x) = 1$, and $u$ has a point discontinuity at $1$, even though $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = u(1)$.

I'm asking to understand if it's justified to simplify the computation of limit of $\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt {v(x)}$, by computing the limit $\lim_{x \to a}v(x)$ only, because it's much simpler (e.g. L'Hopital rule is much simpler to apply). However, it looks like I can do that only when $\lim_{x \to a}v(x)$ exists, but if it does not exist, could it still be that $\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt {v(x)}$ exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be minimal, but the condition that $u$ has continuous inverse function (locally around the limit) is enough.

In this case, $u^{-1}(x)=x^2$ satisfies the condition.